# Get images / media attached to a page by page ID

Tags: plugin-development, themes

I have a series of pages which have images included on them by means of the HTML editor in the admin area. I need to access these while NOT on the the actual page in question, i.e, I need to access these images by the page ID.

I've tried using the following:

`$all the images = get_attached_media( 'image', 31 );`

This returns NULL however, does anyone have a solution here?

Please bear in my mind, I am not looking to access the featured page image here, I am trying to access all images attatched / assigned to a page within the WYSIWYG editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$all_the_images = get_attached_media( 'image', 31 );` *should* return any image attachments for a page the ID of 31 **if** that page has child images.  Meaning, there are images that were uploaded and actually attached to that page, not just upload and *inserted* into that page.

When you use the media uploader (to upload images), from within the Edit screen of the page you're editing, WP automatically makes those images children of that page.  That's what `get_attched_media()` returns.  If you just use the media uploader to browse the media library and insert images into the content body of the page you're editing `get_attched_media()` won't pull those.